# Failed on audioread mp3 file

Tags: matlab

Error information as follows
[Error using audioread>readaudio
File could not be read due to an unexpected error. Reason:  Reason: 为此媒体类型指定的数据无效、不一致或不受此对象的支持。

Error in audioread (line 160)
[y, Fs] = readaudio (filename, range, datatype);](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCp6C.png)

1. Matlab Version R2023b. All toolboxes are included.
2. Mp3 file is ok. And the same code can be run smoothly in others computer.
3. audioread *.wav file is ok.
4. No warning on Win10 Device Manager.
5. Traced error occurred in the code "readPlugin = PluginManager.getInstance.getPluginForRead(filename);" in the function readaudio.

Those are all my efforts.
I would appreciate it if you could help me to solve this problem.